# Space in a string instance can't be read using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using psycopg2 library and iI made a query to select instances from a table in a database. I have run the code in a user interface program and it works however, I get an error when I run it in python. Here is the code:

```
find_id = 'SELECT "serial_number" FROM "LogFiles" WHERE "LogFiles"."user_name" = my product;'
    cur.execute(find_id)
    cur.fetchall()
```

ERROR happen in ^:

> find_id='SELECT "serial_number" FROM "LogFiles" WHERE
> "LogFiles"."user_name" = my ^product ;'

It seems that I need to deal with the space inside of a string as reading of the instance is stopped after my.

I have tried to use `"my product"` and '''my product''' and ''my product'' but they don't work as well.

Comment: is "my_product" a string like "Hot Coffee"?  If so, you need to put that inside quotes and likely escaped quotes.  You might also want to look at parameterized SQL.

Comment: See [Passing Parameters to SQL Queries](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) to learn about parameterised queries for psycopg2.

Comment: When I put it in quotes such as "my product" or ' ' my product ' ' , then the error start from " or ' ' before    my .

Comment: 1) `find_id = 'SELECT "serial_number" FROM "LogFiles" WHERE "LogFiles"."user_name" = %;'` 2) `cur.execute(find_id, ['my product'])`

Comment: That works well!!